# Ошибка "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge" при update

Tags: git, laravel

Изучаю *Laravel*. По своей неопытности залез в директорию *public*, в которой поправил файлы. Затем сделал `push`, чтобы отправить мои изменения по ветке *master* на *bitbucket*.

После этого решил обновить сервер, чтобы изменения появились на сайте, но при `update` появилась ошибка:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: public/js/all.js
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Я не могу исправить ошибку и загрузить обновления на сервер.

Пытался с помощью команды `git rm --cached public/js/all.js` удалить мои правки из индекса, чтобы сделать снова `push`, и потом с репозитория обновить сервер, но появилась новая ошибка:

> Commit failed with error:
>   On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>
> Untracked files:
>       public/fonts/
>       public/i/
>       public/uploads/
>       public/vendor/
>       resources/lang/tg/welcome.php
>       storage/locations.php
>       storage/profs.php
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у Вас на сервере файл изменен `public/js/all.js`

Вы сможете обновить сервер: сделав его коммит `commit`, откатив `checkout` или спрятав `stash`
после чего сервер обновить удастся

а подобное необходимо добавить в исключения `.gitignore`

> ```
> public/uploads/
> public/vendor/
> ```

Comment: Я не силен в git так, что хотел уточнить правильно ли я все понял. Мне на локальном сервере в терминале нужно вести команду: git commit, чтобы зафиксировать изменения?

Comment: А потом спрятать all.js с помощью git stash и запустить push, чтобы отправить изменения на репазиторий, после этого обновить сервер. Верно?

Comment: я Вам написал 3 варианта что можно сделать в случае если на сервере измененный не зафиксированный файл.
не торопитесь. Выведите git status с сервера

Comment: потому как исходя из ответа - все ок.

Comment: Сервер мне выдал это:Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 modified:   public/js/all.js

Comment: сервер Вам тоже самое ответил либо за комментируйте файл "git add <file>..." (если изменения в нем нужны) либо отмените изменения в файле "git checkout -- <file>..."

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все получилось! :)

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сохранить изменения в рабочем кталоге перед мержем:

1. `git stash save`
2. `git merge origin/master`
3. `git stash pop`